How to keep the dimension in RegionImage and Image3DSlices (maybe simple question)?
I want to get slice images as following.
spheres= {{Sphere[{210.346, 851.505, 1252.18}, 4.53991]}, {Sphere[{207.943, 657.272, 151.695}, 17.0464]}, {Sphere[{84.9863, 496.913, 1378.66}, 4.67399]}, {Sphere[{68.223, 1080.54, 53.7008}, 2.54346]}, {Sphere[{797.796, 815.919, 853.71}, 5.66107]}, {Sphere[{960.146, 776.191, 1307.66}, 0.35048]},{Sphere[{185.597, 922.637, 832.621}, 11.9466]}, {Sphere[{1240.58, 219.672, 981.527}, 6.14375]}, {Sphere[{206.35, 269.224, 564.299}, 3.94981]},{Sphere[{497.753, 292.361, 1298.57}, 9.58334]}, {Sphere[{648.244, 662.278, 868.924}, 2.45239]}, {Sphere[{290.336, 1325.9, 982.398}, 10.7862]}, {Sphere[{786.196, 1320.08, 882.984}, 6.75594]}, {Sphere[{1192.97, 712.091, 782.056}, 6.41432]}, {Sphere[{881.397, 716.573, 493.85}, 12.8063]}};
graphics = Graphics3D[spheres, PlotRange -> {{0, 1400}, {0, 1400}, {0, 1400}}, Axes -> True]
reg = RegionImage[DiscretizeGraphics[graphics]];
binarize = reg // FillingTransform // Binarize;
imageslice = Image3DSlices[binarize]

Since I wrote  "PlotRange -> {{0, 1400}, {0, 1400}, {0, 1400}}, Axes -> True" in "graphics", the 3D image seems to be 1400x1400x1400.
I want to get Sliced binarized image of same dimensions. I mean I WANT TO convert this 3D graphic to 1400 2D pictures with 1400x1400 pixel.
However,
Dimensions[ImageData[graphics]]

is {373, 360, 3}, though I expected it as 1400x1400x1400.
Moreover,
Dimensions[imageslice] 

and
Dimensions[imageslice[[1]]]

are {91} and {90,90}, respectively, though I expected to be 1400 and {1400,1400} each.
I think some down sizing has done in the process of "RegionImage" and "Image3DSlices". Do you know how to keep the dimensions while getting 2D image slicing?

"ImageDimensions[ImageData[graphics]] is {373, 360, 3}", means that the raster image data ImageData[graphics] has width 373 pixels, height 360 pixels, and 3 colors (R,G,B)

Oh, I see. Thank you for your kind explaination. Then, I wonder why it isn't {1400, 1400, 3}".

PlotRange doesn't do what you think it does. PlotRange is an option for graphics functions that specifies what range of coordinates to include in a plot. This example from the documentation shows how PlotRange works. {Graphics[{Orange, Disk[]},PlotRange->.9, Axes->True],   Graphics3D[Sphere[],PlotRange-> .9,Axes->True]}. Try the command again without the PlotRange options to see the differences.

Thank you. I tried it now and understood PlotRange does not decide the Dimensions... So how can I fix the dimensions of Graphic3D? In the 2D images, we can try ImageResize, but I don't know  how to do it for 3D graphics.

Correct, changing the size of the image doesn't make the change you need. Instead, try reg  =  RegionImage[DiscretizeGraphics[graphics], RasterSize -> 200]; You can use values larger than 200, but memory usage increases a lot. You can make these changes: spheres = Flatten[{{Sphere ... ]; and graphics = Graphics3D[spheres, Boxed -> False];. Experiment with the Lighting -> None option. Consider balls = spheres /. Sphere -> Ball so maybe you won't need FillingTransform. Use Image3DSlices[reg, ;; ;; 25, 1] to look at a sample of the slices. Change ";; ;; 25" for other views, etc.

In the first place, the radii of your spheres (〜5) are very small comared to the size of your containor box (〜1400). So, even if you get a successful code, each image created by Image3DSlices[] will contain nothing or just a few small dots. Is this really what you want?


Dr. A.Kato   Yes, you are correct and such images is what I really want. Actually, I want to add various size of spheres and the number of spheres will be increased later. The sample I handle is in this scale. The code here is almost minimum size of the spheres.



Dr. creidhne  I converted Sphere to Ball and Lighting -> None, it seems Binarized already. However, RegionImage[DiscretizeGraphics[graphics]] doesn't work. This command I think needed   is used for converting Graphic3D to 3DImage.


As far as I understand from the questions and comments, there is little advantage to using Image3DSlices[] in your problem. If I were you, I would work exclusively with two-dimensional Graphics[].
Suppose I want to see the image obtained by cutting along the plane $z=z_0$. Then, only Sphere[pt,r]'s which satisfy Abs[pt[[3]]-z0]<r are relevant. The cross section of such a sphere is a disk whose center is pt[[1;;2]] in the $x,y$ coordinate system, and whose radius is easily computed by Pythagorean theorem.
So, the code is something like
data = Flatten[spheres];

slice[z_] := 
  Module[{relevant = Select[data, Abs[#[[1, 3]] - z] < #[[2]] &]}, 
   Graphics[
    Disk[#[[1, 1 ;; 2]], Sqrt[#[[2]]^2 - (#[[1, 3]] - z)^2]] & /@ 
     relevant, PlotRange -> {{0, 1400}, {0, 1400}}, Axes -> True, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]];

For example, if you cut at $z=152$, the slice looks like
slice[152]


Of course, you can play with Manipulate[] by changing the value of $z$.
Manipulate[slice[z], {z, 0, 1400}]

Suppose you want to see the slice by a general plane $ax+by+cz=d$. This problem can be converted to the $z=z_{0}$ case by applying GeometricTransformation[] on your data spheres.
Note Added:
The OP wants raster image of size $1400\times1400$. OK, then try this:
slice2[z_] := 
  Module[{relevant = Select[data, Abs[#[[1, 3]] - z] < #[[2]] &]}, 
   Rasterize[
    Graphics[
     Disk[#[[1, 1 ;; 2]], Sqrt[#[[2]]^2 - (#[[1, 3]] - z)^2]] & /@ 
      relevant, PlotRange -> {{0, 1400}, {0, 1400}}], 
    RasterSize -> {1400, 1400}]]; 

ImageDimensions[slice2[152]]
(* {1400, 1400} *)


Dr Kato, Thank you so much for very kind instruction!! The pictures are almost I want. I tried the "Manuplate[slice[z],{z,0,1400}]", which was quite nice. I'm so sorry to bother you but could you tell me a little bit more? I want to convert the slice[152] into 1400x1400 image. When I changed the last part of function "slice" into "Axes -> False", and then tried "ImageData[slice[152]]", which was {720,720,3}. So the pixelsize is now 720x720 as you told me before...

I updated my answer on your request. Please check Note Added.

I am truely grateful to you from the heart, Dr. Kato!!! This is the exact one which I wanted! Thank you VERY much for the your kind guidance. I can't express my thanks enough. Thanks again. I want to follow your answers to other questions in order to study the tips of Mathematica.

You're welcome. The distiction between Graphics and ImageData are important here. The Graphics is a collection of geometric objects whose shapes are expressed (in principle rigorously) by combination of (in)equalities. The coordinates used in Graphics can be atomic size or galaxy size. ImageData is a matrix of brightness or RGB-colors of each pixels, which is just a handy format for displaying images on the screen of PC. The process of converting Graphics into ImagaData is called rendering or rasterizing. But the reverse process is usually impossible, because of information loss.

Hmm...Graphic is in an ideal space, but Image is just the picture of Graphic and Image has less information. That's why we  need rendering or rasterizing. Now I understand the meaning of rendering and rasterizing. Your explaination is very clear! Thanks a lot!!
